# why I can not accept white spaces on field for save in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to save a form with rails, its a simple one, and everytime I try to send a name with a space (like john smith) I dont actually get an error, it returns succcess, but does not save anything, when I try johnsmith then it works.

I checked on my model and I have this

```
  validates :first_name, :allow_blank => true, :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "Only letters allowed" }
```

validating only letters, but accepting spaces, still, when I try, no success.

At my controller I have something like this.

```
name = params[:name].to_s
```

and later

```
@user.atributes = { :weight => weight, :name => name ... and so on
```

at the end I only make a `@user.save`

Any idea how to avoid this problem? I do want to accept spaces on the names, but without getting into security problems.

Thanks

result of the post in my console

```
Started POST "/users/custom" for 192.168.1.21 at 2013-05-21 17:51:06 -0600
Processing by UsersController#custom as JS
  Parameters: {"name"=>"  new user", "lastname"=>" my last name", "mail"=>"newuser@gmail.com", "sex"=>"0" ... n so on}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `first_name` = ' new user', `ssn` = 0, `updated_at` = '2013-05-21 23:51:06' WHERE `users`.`id` = 6
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered users/custom.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 11.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Comment: how are you defining your form?  my URL character escaping senses are tingling.

Comment: Could you try chnging your regex to accept spaces? ^[A-Za-z ]+$ I'm sure you would have seen an error for your failing validation and I'm not hot on regex but I suspect the regex is the cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. You're accepting only letters, whitespace is not a letter. Try something like this: `\A[a-zA-Z,\s]+\z`

BTW rubular is pretty cool tool, if you need to test your regexps.

http://rubular.com/

Comment: +1 Nice catch!  Wonder why he's not seeing a validation error come back?

Comment: Yeah, that's strange but I suspect that validations work and error will be in rendering of the message.

Comment: thats great! it worked!! and yes, its weird why I didnt get any error back, actually, thats one of my problems, I am submiting form via ajax, but still, no problem when submitting.

Comment: @jpganz you can find out what's going on in the terminal where your app server is running. When you submit the form, you should see the request (I assume it'll be POST request) in that window. What does it say?

Comment: thank you @MarekTakac I edited my post, there is any way I give some feedback to my view? I am making with with ajax and a form with haml.

Answer (score 1):

About the validation message not showing up:

If you're doing asynchronous request, you'll need to make your validation on the client side. There are some gems which can help you with this, e.g. [client side validations gem](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations).

Also, if you're using jQuery.ajax() you can use its callback to perform an action after the call (notify user of success or do whatever with DOM you want to):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://some/url.com",
    // rest of your ajax call
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log("Your data:", data); // this will be run after the async. call 
});
```

If you need to debug things like this try [pry](http://pryrepl.org/). Just add to your gemfile:

```
group :test, :development do  
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.9.12'
end
```

Run bundle install, restart server and then you can add:

```
binding.pry
```

wherever you want to stop code execution and inspect current state of your app enviroment in the console.

In your case it would be somewhere at the end of UsersController#custom method. You can then check in your terminal value of `@user`. Methods `@user.valid?` and `@user.errors` will tell you if your @user object is valid and show you an array with all validation errors associated with the object.